# How to put bytes(bits) into byte

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm not very good with bit operations so I would like to ask the following:
I have 4 bytes(bits), which can be either 0 or 1

```
byte a1=0;
byte a2=1;
byte a3=1;
byte a4=0;
```

How to create `byte b` , that has the following bits `a1a2a3a4 0000`  ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
byte a1=0;
byte a2=1;
byte a3=1;
byte a4=0;

byte b = (byte) ((a1 << 7) | (a2 << 6) | (a3 << 5) | (a4 << 4));
```

And see this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).